# Clarification on karma running on multiple browsers

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

Recently I have had a need to run my tests on more than just Chrome being that my new web app needs to work on more than just chrome so here we go:

This doesn't seem like it would be possible but just in case it is:

I am running on ubuntu and have karma setup to run on Chrome and Firefox; it works like a charm.

I was thinking about running them on ie and safari but it occurs to me i will probably need to run these tests on a vm i suppose because the binaries for safari and ie wont work on ubuntu?

Is this the right assumption or is there a way to run karma tests on browsers that are not supported by your OS i.e. use the safari launcher on ubuntu and have them run the tests.

Doesn't make much sense to me that this would be possible but if anyone has a way of getting this working i would be really interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the right assumption or is there a way to run karma tests on browsers that are not supported by your OS i.e. use the safari launcher on ubuntu and have them run the tests.

The way you expressed your question, the answer to this is "no", because Karma won't allow your OS to run browsers that you would not be able to run without Karma.

**However**, what you *can* do is use Karma with a service like Sauce Labs or Browser Stack. These are essentially virtual server farms dedicated to running browsers. Karma has plugins available for both. With these services and the plugins, you can start a browser on any of the major desktop OSes and on some smartphone and tablet devices, and run tests on them.

I'm sure you could spin your own local VM to do the same thing if you wanted to but it is a rather involved task.

Comment: i expected as much, thanks very much for confirming my assumptions and giving me another avenue to look down.